# Showing that estimating $Y$ from $X$ via linear regression and estimating $X$ from $Y$ via linear regression are not invertible

Tags: regression, mathematical-statistics, least-squares, psychometrics

This is a follow up to the question [Regression on population values?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/519384/regression-on-population-values).

In the theory of test equating (see, e.g., *Test Equating, Scaling, and Linking* by Kolen and Brennan (2014)), suppose we have a group of examinees whom we randomly assign one of two exam forms, say form X and form Y.

Let $X$ be a random variable representing scores of form X, and similarly for $Y$. Letting $\sigma(X)$ denote the standard deviation of a random variable $X$, **linear equating** assumes that
$$\dfrac{X - \mathbb{E}[X]}{\sigma(X)} = \dfrac{Y - \mathbb{E}[Y]}{\sigma(Y)}$$
with probability one. To interpret the above, suppose we have a particular score $X = x$ from form X; we would use the equation above to yield an equivalent score for form Y.

Solving for $Y$ in the above equation yields
$$Y = \dfrac{\sigma(Y)}{\sigma(X)}\cdot X + \mathbb{E}[Y] - \dfrac{\sigma(Y)}{\sigma(X)}\cdot \mathbb{E}[X]\text{.}\tag{1}$$
This can be interpreted as a linear equation of $X$, with slope $\dfrac{\sigma(Y)}{\sigma(X)}$ and intercept $\mathbb{E}[Y] - \dfrac{\sigma(Y)}{\sigma(X)}\cdot \mathbb{E}[X]$.

As stated in the prior question, Kolen and Brennan mention:

> The equation for linear equating... is deceptively like a linear regression equation. The difference is that, for linear regression, the $\sigma(Y)/\sigma(X)$ terms are multiplied by the correlation between $X$ and $Y$.

Explaining this has already been well covered by the linked question above.

Kolen and Brennan then go on to say:

> However, a linear regression equation does not
> qualify as an equating function because the regression of X on Y is different from
> the regression of Y on X, unless the correlation coefficient is 1. For this reason,
> regression equations cannot, in general, be used as equating functions.

To be more precise about this, with the inclusion of the correlation coefficient from performing linear regression in $(1)$, based on the above discussion, we obtain
$$\begin{align}
Y &= \dfrac{\sigma(Y)}{\sigma(X)}\rho_{X, Y}\cdot X + \mathbb{E}[Y] - \dfrac{\sigma(Y)}{\sigma(X)}\rho_{X, Y}\cdot \mathbb{E}[X] \\
&= \mathbb{E}[Y] + \dfrac{\sigma(Y)}{\sigma(X)}\rho_{X, Y}\left(X - \mathbb{E}[X]\right)\text{.}
\end{align}$$
Denote this function $r_Y(X)$ - i.e., the regression equator of $X$ to $Y$ based on a linear regression of $Y$ on $X$ - more specifically:
$$r_Y(X) = \mathbb{E}[Y] + \dfrac{\sigma(Y)}{\sigma(X)}\rho_{X, Y}\left(X - \mathbb{E}[X]\right)\tag{2}$$
If we were to perform regression of $X$ on $Y$, the regression equator of $Y$ to $X$ would be
$$r_X(Y) = \mathbb{E}[X] + \dfrac{\sigma(X)}{\sigma(Y)}\rho_{X, Y}\left(Y - \mathbb{E}[Y]\right)\tag{3}$$

**What I am merely trying to show is the following:**

- If $Y$ is the response variable and $X$ is the explanatory variable in a linear regression, given $X = x$, the corresponding value $y = y(x)$ due to this regression would result in a **different** value of $X$ if we were to find the corresponding value of $X$ when looking at the regression based on $X$ being the response variable and $Y$ being the explanatory variable using $Y = y$ (and vice versa).

**In other words, my aim is to show that $r_Y(r_X(Y)) \neq Y$ and $r_X(r_Y(X)) \neq X$ for $\rho_{X, Y} \neq 1$.**

However, I suspect something is wrong with my equations $(2)$ or $(3)$. If $X$ is the response variable and $Y$ is the explanatory variable, we obtain
$$r_X(r_Y(X)) = \mathbb{E}[X] + \dfrac{\sigma(X)}{\sigma(r_Y(X))}\rho_{r_Y(X), X}\left(r_Y(X) - \mathbb{E}[r_Y(X)]\right)$$
One can easily see that $\mathbb{E}[r_Y(X)] = \mathbb{E}[Y]$. Through variance and standard deviation calculations, one can also see that
$$\text{Var}(r_Y(X)) = \rho^2_{X, Y}\text{Var}(Y)$$
so that
$$\sigma(r_Y(X)) = |\rho_{X, Y}|\text{Var}(Y)\text{.}$$
Now
\begin{align}
\text{Cov}(r_Y(X), X) &= \text{Cov}\left( \mathbb{E}[Y] + \dfrac{\sigma(Y)}{\sigma(X)}\rho_{X, Y}\left(X - \mathbb{E}[X]\right), X\right) \\
&= \dfrac{\sigma(Y)}{\sigma(X)}\rho_{X, Y}\text{Var}(X) \\
&= \rho_{X, Y}\sigma(Y)\sigma(X)\text{.}
\end{align}
Therefore,
$$\rho_{r_Y(X), X} = \dfrac{\rho_{X, Y}\sigma(Y)\sigma(X)}{|\rho_{X, Y}|\sigma(Y)\sigma(X)} = \dfrac{\rho_{X, Y}}{|\rho_{X, Y}|}\text{.}$$
Hence,
\begin{align}
r_X(r_Y(X)) &= \mathbb{E}[X] + \dfrac{\rho_{X, Y}}{|\rho_{X, Y}|} \cdot \dfrac{\sigma(X)}{|\rho_{X, Y}|\sigma(Y)}\left[\mathbb{E}[Y] + \rho_{X, Y}\cdot \dfrac{\sigma(Y)}{\sigma(X)}(X - \mathbb{E}[X]) - \mathbb{E}[Y] \right] \\
&= \mathbb{E}[X] + \dfrac{\rho_{X, Y}^2}{|\rho_{X, Y}|^2}(X - \mathbb{E}[X]) \\
&= X\text{.}
\end{align}
Thus, I suspect something is wrong here. Could someone point out exactly what I did wrong?

Comment: Aren't all these issues addressed at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/22718?  I'm unsure, because your notation "$r_X(r_Y(X))$" doesn't make sense: you can't regress the mathematical object $r_Y(X)$ against $X,$ but that's how you have tried to define $r_X.$

Comment: @whuber I've read that particular link several times, and haven't figured out how to translate that to this problem. Maybe I should use a different notation for this, but the intent of the notation "$r_X(r_Y(X))$" is to say this: take a value $X$, and use regression to get a value $Y$ (hence $r_Y(X)$). But if we take this particular value of $Y$ given by $r_Y(X)$ and try to estimate $X$ using a regression with $Y$ being the explanatory variable and $X$ being the response variable, $r_X(r_Y(X))$ should not be equal to $X$ because these yield two regression lines when $\rho_{X, Y} \neq 1$.

Comment: @whuber I suspect, then, something is wrong with my equations (2) and (3).

Comment: Those equations are identical (because $\rho_{X,Y}=\rho_{Y,X},$ they differ merely by changing the roles of $X$ and $Y$ in the notation), so they are either both correct or both wrong!  But, as I remarked, your notation makes no sense, so it's likely confusing your algebra. You can simplify your work (greatly) by assuming $E[X]=E[Y]=0.$ You may even assume $SD(X)=SD(Y)=1.$ It's unfortunate that the other thread doesn't have any adequate figures: you might find it helpful to plot both regression lines *within the same plot.* Scale the axes so that each variable's SD is the same length.

Comment: @whuber Ugh, I've been frustrated trying to learn psychometrics on my own since they aren't precise with their mathematical definitions. Back to the drawing board.

Comment: @whuber I agree completely that *visually* that this should make sense. Kolen and Brennan explain this visually as well, but I'd like to formally justify this.

Comment: It might be more helpful for me to just stick with more traditional statistics notation than trying to make sense of the notation Kolen and Brennan use.

Comment: After you choose units appropriately (that is, by standardizing both variables), the regression of $Y$ against $X$ is $Y = \rho X,$ the regression of $X$ against $Y$ is $X=\rho Y$ (mathematically equivalent to $Y = X/\rho$), and the linear equation is $X=Y.$ That's perfectly rigorous and exposes all the relevant concepts.

Comment: @whuber Thank you, that's extremely helpful. I'll work out the details for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without loss of generality, assume $\mathbb{E}[X] = \mathbb{E}[Y] = 0$ and $\text{Var}(X) = \text{Var}(Y) = 1$.

Then $$r_{Y}(X) = \rho_{X, Y} \cdot X$$
and
$$r_{X}(Y) = \rho_{X, Y} \cdot Y\text{.}$$
Hence, as long as $\rho_{X, Y} \neq 1$,
$$r_{Y}(r_{X}(Y)) = r_{Y}(\rho_{X, Y} Y) =  \rho_{r_{X}(Y), Y}\rho_{X, Y}Y $$
Now
$$\rho_{r_X(Y), Y} = \rho_{\rho_{X, Y}Y, Y} = \dfrac{\rho_{X, Y}\cdot \text{Var}(Y)}{|\rho_{X, Y}|\cdot \text{Var}(Y)} = \pm 1$$
hence
$$r_{Y}(r_{X}(Y)) = \pm \rho_{X, Y}Y \neq Y\text{.}$$

Thus, $r_Y \neq r_X^{-1}$.

Comment: You lost me at the third line, because if $r_Y(\cdot)$ is supposed to be $\rho_{\cdot,Y}(\cdot),$ as indicated in the first line, where $(\cdot)$ indicates some random variable, then in the expression "$r_Y(r_X(Y))$" we see $(\cdot)=r_X(Y)=\rho_{X,Y}Y$, giving $$r_Y(r_X(Y))=\rho_{r_X(Y), Y}(r_X(Y))=\rho_{\rho_{X,Y}Y,Y}(\rho_{X,Y}Y).$$ Obviously $\rho_{\rho_{X,Y}Y,Y}=\pm 1,$ simplifying the result to $\pm\rho_{X,Y}Y.$

Comment: @whuber Ah, you're completely right. Thanks for that.

Comment: @whuber Thanks, I've made the edits.